# Compilar y ejecutar un proyecto de java desde la terminal de Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, terminal, compilar, jar

Quiero compilar y crear el **jar ejecutable** de un proyecto de java

```
javac -d  src/Inicio/Visual/*.java
```

Este es el comando que he intentado y me sale el siguiente error:

> javac: directory not found: src/Inicio/Visual/*.java
>       Usage: javac  
>       use -help for a list of possible options

[image: Esta es la jerarquia de clases la acrpeta del proyecto la tengo en el escritorio]

Comment: Buenas, estas sguro de haber puesto bien la ruta? no veo la carpeta Visual.  Prueba a poner "src/Inicio/Visual.java" sin la barra "/"

Comment: Si utilizas librerias tambien tendras que lincarlas con la opcion "-cp [libreria]"

Comment: ```
javac tucodigo.java java -jar tucodigo.jar
```

Comment: Tal vez quiere Visual.java en lugar de Visual/.java ?